# RMarkdown can't find 'pdflatex.fmt' file

Tags: r-markdown, pdflatex, tinytex

I am trying RMarkdown for the first time, using the very first example in Yihui's book "R Markdown A Definitive Guide":

```
---
title: "Hello R Markdown"
author: "Awesome Me"
date: "2018-02-14"
output: pdf_document
---
```

`This is a paragraph in an R Markdown document.`

`Below is a code chunk:`

```
options(tinytex.verbose = TRUE)
fit = lm(dist ~ speed, data = cars)
b = coef(fit)
plot(cars)
abline(fit)
```

`` The slope of the regression is `r b[1] ``

I installed TinyTex using the following as per Yihui's comments [here](https://yihui.org/tinytex/#comment-4039915586):

`devtools::install_github('yihui/tinytex')`

`tinytex:::install_prebuilt()`

Running `tinytex:::is_tinytex()` yields TRUE.

Clicking *Knit* gives me the following output. There is an error line `I can't find the format file 'pdflatex.fmt'`

```
processing file: Testpdf1.Rmd
  |.......................                                               |  33%
  ordinary text without R code

  |...............................................                       |  67%
label: unnamed-chunk-1
  |......................................................................| 100%
   inline R code fragments

"C:/Users/xxxxxx/Documents/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS Testpdf1.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output Testpdf1.tex --self-contained --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine pdflatex --variable graphics --lua-filter "C:/Users/xxxxxx/Documents/R/R-3.6.1/library/rmarkdown/rmd/lua/pagebreak.lua" --lua-filter "C:/Users/xxxxxx/Documents/R/R-3.6.1/library/rmarkdown/rmd/lua/latex-div.lua" --variable "geometry:margin=1in" 
output file: Testpdf1.knit.md

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
I can't find the format file `pdflatex.fmt'!

kpathsea: Running mktexfmt pdflatex.fmt

The command name is C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\mktexfmt
I was unable to find any missing LaTeX packages from the error log Testpdf1.log.
! kpathsea: Running mktexfmt pdflatex.fmt

! The command name is C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\mktexfmt

Error: LaTeX failed to compile Testpdf1.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging 
tips. See Testpdf1.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

I am trying to compile a pdf file. I am running Windows behind my company firewall. Searching for that file 'pdflatex.fmt' on my computer yields nothing. I have been searching for solution on the net for a while but can't relate to the problem. Does anyone know how I go about solving this?

Answer (score 2):

**Update on 2020/05/14**: this is unlikely to be the solution to [the recent breakage in TeX Live](https://github.com/yihui/tinytex/issues/210). If anyone reached here through searches, you have to wait until the breakage is resolved.

---

It may be the same issue as [this one](https://github.com/yihui/tinytex/issues/177#issuecomment-578988789), so please try

```r
tinytex::tlmgr_install(c('texlive-scripts', 'dehyph-exptl'))
```

Comment: Thanks. It turns out my company firewall blocked the installation of tinytex (or at least some of the package). I followed the same steps on my personal laptop and it worked fine.

Comment: @TristanTran Thanks for letting me know!